# How to add Pandas Dataframe to multiple worksheets starting from FIRST CELL?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I am trying to add Pandas dataframe to all the worksheets in an Excel file.However the starting header index is always becoming B1 wheres I am trying to fit it from A1.

Below is the code:

```
import os
import xlwt
from xlwt.Workbook import *
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlsxwriter
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

Categories = ["Column" + str(column) for column in range(1,10)]

wb1 = Workbook()
for i in range(1,5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("1_"+ str(i))
for i in range(5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("2_"+ str(i))
for i in range(5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("3_"+ str(i))
for i in range(5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("4_"+ str(i))
for i in range(5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("5_"+ str(i))
for i in range(5):
    ws = wb1.create_sheet("6_"+ str(i))

wb1.save('FrameFiles.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=Categories)
book = load_workbook('FrameFiles.xlsx')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('FrameFiles.xlsx',engine='openpyxl')

writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
for i in wb1.sheetnames:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i,index=True,startrow=1,startcol=1)
    writer.save()
```

And the output is coming as following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FUZW.png)

I want the header to start from A1 position not B1.I have tried with startrow=0 and startcol=0 also but the result is same. Any suggestion to solve this issue would be highy appreciated.

Comment: panas treats/counts first location (column or row) from 0, - adjust accordingly... Startrow=0 and etc

Answer (score 1):

The empty column is your index column but you have no index in your dataframe so it is empty.  try using index=False and you should get what you are expecting

```
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=i,index=False,startrow=0,startcol=0)
```